# Delete folders old than certain days

Tags: windows, batch, files-folders

I want to delete some specified folders (named yyyy-mm-dd) with more than 10 days old but my script does not work. Please advise how to rectify it.

```
REM Remove Folders Old than 10 days
FORFILES /p “d:\testing” /S /m d:\testing\*-*-* /D -10 /C “cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q 
@path”
```

[image: folder]

Comment: What if a folder is created on the last day of January, and you run the batch file on the eleventh day of February? It won't delete the folder, because 31>11. This approach doesn't take into account that the number of the day resets each month.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to do this in Batch imho. Why not use a programming language (e.g. AutoIt)?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter which month. I just prefer to create a batch file to do the deletion job.